# UFT support to telerik control

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, hp-uft

We are trying to automate one of our desktop application using UFT but we are facing problem with telerik controls. UFT is unable to identify controls for eg • Custom DropDownList (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDropDownList) and 3rd party GridControl (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView) UFT not able to access. 
Please tell me is it possible to automate telerik control using UFT or we need some additional setting for this ..

Answer (score 1):

We can automate telrik controls using UFT. The biggest problem in doing so is that UFT does not know how to identify the objects and all of the objects will be identified as RAD controls.

You will have to write your own functions to execute tests on these controls. First you will have to find out which native function or property can be used for a particular control(this is a time consuming process), after that you will have to write your own function to either set the native property or call the native function to perform the operation on the control

Below is the example of what I will create in UFT for executing tests on telrik controls within UFT

Below is the example of such a function to set the text on telrik controls

```
'''This function will set the text for the telrik controls

'''OprObject is the reference of the object, name is the name string for the object to write the logs, object type will decide which native operation to be performed and value to be set is the actual value to be set

Public Function SetText(ByRef OprObject, ByVal ObjectName, Byval ObjectType, ByVal ValueToBeSet)

'''Check if the object is loaded

CheckLoaded(OprObject, true, ObjectName, ObjectType)

Select Case UCASE(ObjectType)

  Case "COMBOBOX"

       '''For RadComboBox this should work, not sure because I have only worked on a web based telrik app

        OprObject.Object.Text = ValueToBeSet

  Case "TEXTBOX"

       '''' For Text Box we can just use 

       OprObject.Click

       OprObject.Type ValueToBeSet

  ''' add other cases here

end select

End Function
```

To get the list of native functions and properties add the RadControl to the OR and then add the RadControl in your keyword view like below

```
Browser("").........RadObject("").Object.
```

Once you type . after the object you will see the list of properties and functions there (Make sure that your application is open and your object is visible inside the application).

You can also do this with object spy, but object spy wont give the complete list(sometimes you will have nested objects which will not be visible in object spy like RadControl.Object.Customer.Name, where name will not be visible in object spy and when you try to set something to customer in code UFT will throw error).

I wont recommend using insight objects here, because then you will just be automating your whole application as image and any changes in the application will break your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Is object spy able to identify the objects? Is uft able to click on the dropdown list? If no, you can still use "Insight object" identification technique. ie identify the very image of an object... Also if it is java based u could try and enable the java plugin...let me know what worked